# Service Fabric Service has a yellow triangle icon

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm using VS2017 15.5.6, with the latest SF tooling, SF SDK, and SF runtime.

When I create a new SF app, any service I add has a yellow triangle icon. No errors come up when building the solution. When I hover over the reference nothing popups up. How can I find out what the problem is?

Thank you.

Comment: See this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-health-introduction

Comment: @MegaTron Thank you for the link. However, the yellow triangle is inside Visual Studio itself, when working with the source code. The icon shows up in the solution tree, next to the added project in the Services node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft confirmed via the developer community portal that this [is a known bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/190258/service-fabric-yellow-triangle-on-the-services.html) they are investigating.

Comment: It would be greate to leave the link to that bug

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/190258/service-fabric-yellow-triangle-on-the-services.html